# asp.net identity LoginView not switching to LoggedInTemplate

Tags: asp.net, captcha, asp.net-identity, loginview

I have just started working on ASP.NET Identity. I created a web forms project in VS2013 using the Web Forms template.

Then I added BotDetect CAPTCHA in Register.aspx. I Registered the first user so that the Identity schema is created. so far so good.

Now, I observe a very strange thing - I start debugging my application - it shows me the home page. I click on "Log In" menu and the login page is shown. I enter the credential and click on Login. The user successfully logs-in (`signinManager.PasswordSignIn` returns `SignInStatus.Success`); however the `LoginView` does not switch to `LoggedInTemplate`.

Now, I just go to Register page and then go to Login page, then Login and this time the `LoginView` switches to `LoggedInTemplate` properly.

This has happened consistently - unless I go to the Register page the LoginView won't switch to LoggedInView.

Further, I commented the CAPTCHA code (but not the configuration done in the `web.config`). Now, even if I go to Register and then try to Login nothing happens (LoginView remains in `AnonymousTemplate`).

Is there any connection between `LoginView` and `BotDetect CAPTCHA`?

Please let me know if any more info is needed.

Thank you.

> UPDATE:

I removed the BotCAPTCHA entirely from the project and now the `LoginView` correctly switches to `LoggedInTemplate`! My guess is that BotCAPTCHA does URL Rewriting and this is affecting it. I have posted this to BotCAPTCHA support and will Update here once they reply me.

Comment: Did you get a reply and/or solve the issue somehow?

Comment: No, I haven't; however I think it's happening (most probably) because of "Friendly URLs" package in VS2013. If I remove this from the project then BotDetect CAPTCHA works.

Comment: My problem seems to disappear for now (because it appeared very inconsistently. |only on correct credentials, sometimes loginview didn't change into loggedintemplate and the cookie didn't created..|) Thank you for pointing my to the right package... I haven't removed the package though, I rolled `Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Core` back to version 1.0.1 I suppose they did something strange to the `Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Core` package at version 1.0.2.. :)

Comment: My problem relapsed... :( I'll go back one more version back and then try to remove Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Core completely. I cant believe there is no error messages...